# Какова этимология слова "вечер"?

Tags: этимология

В одном этимологическом словаре (А.Г. Ильяхов "Античные корни в русском языке", 2010) написано:

Корни слова ***вечер*** просматриваются в греческом Hesper – так эллины называли древнее божество вечерней звезды. Это одно из прозвищ планеты Венеры. Как утренняя звезда она называлась в Греции Эосфор или Фосфор (римское Люцифер). Римляне назвали звезду Vesper (от лат. vespera – вечер).

Насколько корректна эта информация?

Как считается, слово ***вечер*** имеет неясную этимологию, есть несколько версий.

Вопрос: Какой вариант происхождения слова наиболее вероятен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А. Г. Ильяхов по образованию и по профессии совсем не лингвист, а инженер-строитель, при этом в его гипотезе усматриваются признаки т. н. наивной лингвистики, подробнее см. [статью](http://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/430720/O_professionalnoy_i_lyubitelskoy_lingvistike) «О профессиональной и любительской лингвистике» академика Зализняка. Я советовал бы относиться к этой книге скептически.

Самую актуальную научную информацию о происхождении этого слова мы можем найти в Русском этимологическом словаре академика Аникина, на сс. 77–78 [седьмого выпуска](ftp://istorichka.ru/Slavjanovedenie/Anikin_Russkij_etimologicheskij_slovar%60/Vyp.7.2013.pdf). Не буду приводить цитат, а перескажу по возможности кратко своими словами.

Единый термин для обозначения вечера однозначно восстанавливается для славянского ([*večerъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/ve%C4%8Der%D1%8A)) и, далее, балто-славянского ([*wekeras](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Balto-Slavic/wekeras)) праязыков. Есть гипотеза, что последняя праформа отдалённо родственна (родственна, но не восходит — т. е. как N-юродный брат, а не как прямой потомок) греческому ἕσπερος и латинскому vesper, упоминаемым выше, восходя вместе с ними к праиндоевропейскому языку (она, в частности, представлена в английском Викисловаре по ссылкам выше). Однако против неё высказаны и обоснованные возражения, в суть которых я не буду здесь углубляться. Из альтернативных гипотез Аникин упоминает сравнение праформ этого слова с праформой слова «веко».

Таким образом, учёные восстановили эволюцию слова вплоть до второго тысячелетия до н. э. (предположительное время распада балто-славянского языкового единства), о более отдалённых деталях происхождения существуют по крайней мере две гипотезы, и консенсуса насчёт них нет.